# Grouping observations by ID while also creating characteristic variables

Tags: stata, survey, dummy-variable

I'm working with a survey for individuals in Ecuador and I want to analyse the characteristics of each household. Every individual has a houseID, so I guess I would need to group them using that variable while also creating some extra variables regarding their characteristics: for example, a dummy that is 1 if the household has two women or more. I will post an example below.

I would know how to do this in R (group_by), but I haven't found a similar command in Stata.

A simplified version of my data would be:

```
houseID         femaleDummy   maleDummy
10000000001     1             0
10000000001     1             0
10000000001     0             1
10000000002     0             1
10000000002     0             1
```

And I would like to get something like

```
houseID         twoFemalesormoreDummy
10000000001     1
10000000002     0
```

Comment: dude if the solution solves your question, please accept it. thanks

Comment: Sorry! I was sure I had done it. The solution was perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very easy my friend

```
gen d_female = femaleDummy == 1   
bysort houseID: egen total_female = total(d_female)
bysort houseID: gen dummy = total_female >= 2
```

Comment: You don't need the first statement if the second is amended to `bysort houseID: egen total_female = total(femaleDummy == 1)`.  Note that OP wants 2 or more so the code should end `>= 2`.